# Check and get only Int's out of an Array of Strings

Tags: arrays, swift, string, int, swift3

Im currently working on a small app for chemical calculations. Im trying to program a Mol Calculator in which you just have to enter the sum formula and the amount of it. Without any numbers it works perfectly, for example if i enter `NaCl` with an amount of `100` grams (you enter the gram in a different text field) you get about 1.73 mol, which is the correct solution.

What i want to do now is that i can add numbers, for example `Na2Cl4`. In my method, the string is splitted up properly, if you print it you get `["Na", "2", "Cl", "4"]` but i don't know how i can get the Int's out and remember to which element they were assigned to (2 to Na and 4 to Cl, because i need to multiply the mol/g with the 2).

I tried the following:
The number will always be on a odd index (Na at 0, 2 at 1, Cl at 2, 4 at 3), so i tried to put every element at a odd index into a new array :

```
var i = 0
    var testarray = [String]()

    for content in splitted {
        if i % 2 == 0 {

        }else {
        testarray.append(content)
        }
        print(content)
        i += 1
    }
```

splitted is the [String] array which contains the splitted sum formula. The result i get if i print out content is 2 and 4 which is fine but if i enter for example Na10 i get 1 and 0 which is not good, also it does not know to which element it was assigned to.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem that i can get the Int values out of the string array and remember to which element they were assigned to ?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Heres the code how i split the string:

```
let splitted = summenformel.characters.splitBefore(separator: { $0.isUpperCase }).map{String($0)}
```

and the extensions:

```
    extension Sequence {
    func splitBefore(
        separator isSeparator: (Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool
        ) rethrows -> [AnySequence<Iterator.Element>] {
        var result: [AnySequence<Iterator.Element>] = []
        var subSequence: [Iterator.Element] = []

        var iterator = self.makeIterator()
        while let element = iterator.next() {
            if try isSeparator(element) {
                if !subSequence.isEmpty {
                    result.append(AnySequence(subSequence))
                }
                subSequence = [element]
            }
            else {
                subSequence.append(element)
            }
        }
        result.append(AnySequence(subSequence))
        return result
    }
}

extension Character {
    var isUpperCase: Bool { return String(self) == String(self).uppercased() }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how you created splitted

Comment: Consider to use regular expression for example `[A-Z]([a-z]+)?(\\d+)?` since an element starts always with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the class is very big, go check it out on my github! [link] (https://github.com/andinator/ProChemistry/blob/master/ProChemistry/CalculatorBrain.swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach with regular expression

The regex searches for:

*a capital letter followed by optional lowercase letters followed by optional numbers*.

```
let string = "Na10Cl4"

let pattern = "([A-Z]([a-z]+)?)(\\d+)?"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count))
for match in matches {
  let elementRange = match.rangeAt(1) // capture group of the element
  let element = (string as NSString).substring(with: elementRange)
  print("element", element)
  let quantityRange = match.rangeAt(3) // capture group of the quantity
  let quantity : Int
  if quantityRange.location != NSNotFound {
    quantity = Int((string as NSString).substring(with: quantityRange))!
  } else {
    quantity = 1
  }
  print("quantity", quantity)
}
```

Comment: best working solution for me! Thank you very much! You really made my day!

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you have a couple questions here.  I'll try and tackle them all.

**Splitting the String**

```
var elements: [String];
var nums: [Int];
let input: String = "Na2Cl4"
for (index,char) in input.characters.enumerate() {
    if char.lowercaseString != char {  //Is uppercase letter
        elements.append(char + input[index + 1]) //Add the element "Na" to the elements array.
    }else if Int(char) != nil {
        var tempInt = char
        if input[index + 1] != nil {
             tempInt += input[index + 1]
        }
        nums.append(tempInt) //Add the integer 4 to the array.
    }
}
```

So this would give you to arrays with `["Na","Cl"]` and `[2,4]`.  If you input `Na10Cl25`, you would have the same `elements` array with `nums` as `[10,25]`

**The Math**

Now with two seperate arrays you can easily know which `Int` belongs to which element.

```
for (index,value) in elements.enumerate(){
    let thisElementValue = (mol / g) * nums[index]
    print("There are \(nums[index]) \(value) molecules")
}
```

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari exactly.

Comment: Ok, then how about you store the element and the molecule values in seperate arrays.  That way when you reference `element[0]` and `mol[0]` you will have separate values, but you'll also know which element it pertains to.  You haven't shown you do the splitting.

Comment: I will try it for sure, but as i said im very new to swift so it probably gonna take some time until i made it 'compatible' to my code because atm i put every found element into a new array and compare it with a dictionary in which the mol/g is stored for example ["Na": 23, "Cl" : 35]

Comment: I dont know how to edit the code, because i already know how to split up the string so therefore this step is not needed.

Comment: Yes but you're not storing each value in separate arrays which would be the best route for doing the calculations you are.

Comment: i get an error that char has no member lowercaseString

Comment: Convert it to a string.  `String(char).lowercaseString`